# Adding bibliography to appendices in latex

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am writing my thesis and I am using the `chapterbib` option. While it makes beautiful bibliographies for my chapters, I can't get it to do the same thing for my appendices.

The preamble:

```
\documentclass[pdftex, 11pt, onecolumn, openany]{report}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}  
\usepackage{appendix}  
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}  
\usepackage{chapterbib}

\begin{document}  
...  
\include{background}  
\include{ATRPcomp}  
\include{CCTcomp} 
\appendix  
\include{AppCCT}  
\end{document}
```

In each of my chapter sections and appendix I have:

```
\chapter{Compartmentalization in Catalytic Chain Transfer}  
...  
\bibliography{references}
```

Does the `chapterbib` also work for appendices or is there another option that could help?

Comment: In what way is it not working? And there is a duplicate `\usepackage{chapterbib}` in your code, one instance with and one instance without option.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the package to work also within the appendix. I fact, when you issue the command `\appendix` the sectioning commands' behavior is the same, except for the numbering (and perhaps the heading).

In the main matter, the chapter command
`\chapter{CCTcomp}`
gives you

**7 CCtcomp**

(7 is an example). The commands sequence

```
\appendix
\chapter{AppCCT}
```

gives you

**A AppCCT**

The bibliography shoud work properly.

Comment: The \appendix is changing my Table of Contents appropriately, but no bibliography is appearing in my appendices although the code \bibliography{references} is the same in those chapters as the main chapters in the text.

I am also now using only
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}

and have deleted the second "\usepackage{chapterbib}"

Please help!
Thanks :)